# Laradock multiproject, stripe-cli --forward-to issue

Tags: docker, stripe, webhook

tengo el siguiente problema:

Estoy trabajando con laradock configurado para trabajar multiproyectos. Necesito probar los webhooks para lo cual utilizo
stripe-cli. Ejecuto `docker run --rm -it stripe/stripe-cli listen --forward-to host.docker.internal --api-key xxxxxxxx` pero necesito redirigir
a **xxxx.localhost.test/webhooks/stripe**. Ojalá me pudieran apoyar en orientarme a como lograrlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Comunicación en el idioma oficial del sitio (español) por favor.

Comment: Ya lo hice. Muchas gracias por la observación.